# Would all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Matrix A uniquely determine A?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

More precisely,let's say A is n*n matrix

1.If all n eigenvalues and eigenvectors are known,
does it uniquely determine A?

2.let's say A have r ( r<n) n eigenvectors, and
all r eigenvalues and eigenvectors are known
, does it uniquely determine A? (the question is
different from question 1 since A has less than n eigenvectors,
maybe it has more freedom?)

Comment: 1) Yes. Look up eigen-decomposition. 2) no.

Answer (score 2):

Claiming that you know $n$ eigenvectors means your matrix is diagonalisable.
In this case the eigenvectors can be used as a base in which $A$ is simply diagonal and fully determined.

Now don"t be mistaken if some eigenvalues have a multiplicity greater than $1$ then there is a risk of $A$ being non-diagonalisable. In this case you will get less eigenvectors than eigenvalues counted with their multiplicity and cannot reconstitute $A$.

Just take for instance the simple Jordan block $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ it has only one eigenvector $u=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and this is clearly not sufficient to reconstitute $A$.

So you have to be precise in your wording because the answer may differ.

Comment: "Given $n$ eigenvectors" doesn't imply that the eigenvalues are different.

Comment: thx, i got overhyped there, removed it.

Comment: Although it is obvious, for first sentence, OP should also specify that $n$ eigenvectors corresponding to $n$ eigenvalues are known. Two different matrices can have same set of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Jordan block brings out another question, does any matrix has at least one eigenvector?

Comment: By definition of eigenvalue, there is always at least one eigenvector per eigenvalue (not counting multiplicity)., In the Jordan block, it'll correspond to the first column where there are zeroes below.